# Where does Stackoverflow.com's search description come from?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I do not see a meta tag with description in the source code of stackoverflow.com. But searching for stackoverflow on google, shows the following description.

> A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site
>   for programmers.

[image: stackoverflow google search]

The bing search has an extra line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [How to programmatically provide site structure and url path to Google search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3796793).

The text is taken from the [DMOZ entry for Stack Overflow](http://www.dmoz.org/Reference/Ask_an_Expert/Computers_and_Technology/):

> A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers.

Apparently, Bing uses [a different entry from DMOZ](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Resources/Chats_and_Forums/) instead:

> A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers. Questions and answers displayed by user votes and tags.