# Why is Stack Overflow the only Stack Exchange site with a search engine description?

Tags: feature-request, seo

**Edit: Due to the [new banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174747/do-we-really-need-the-double-step-to-get-rid-of-the-new-about-banner/174769#174769) shown to new users, all sites now have an accurate search engine description.**

According to [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155071/168660) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3796793/882455), StackOverflow's description in search engines *("A language-agnostic yada yada yada...")* is due to its [DMOZ entry](http://www.dmoz.org/Reference/Ask_an_Expert/Computers_and_Technology/).

Unfortunately, it is the only site that has such a description. Not even the other trilogy sites (SF,SU) have one, let alone SE 2.0 sites.

First, why does Stack Overflow rely on a DMOZ entry instead of, say, a meta tag? And why is it the only site to merit a meaningful description? The others just pull up the question that was on top when the search engine most recently indexed it.

(Anticipating an answer saying: "It would require writing up a description for 99+ sites". But even a static SE network description would be an improvement.)

Comment: You'd have to ask the DMOZ editors. It's very likely that they're sitting in the unreviewed queue there (and there's several million other sites waiting for review).

Comment: [How to suggest a site to the Open Directory](http://www.dmoz.org/docs/en/add.html) & [Become an Editor at the Open Directory Project](http://www.dmoz.org/public/apply?cat=Reference/Ask_an_Expert/Computers_and_Technology)

Comment: I've lost count of how many times I've submitted [my website](http://quickmediasolutions.com) to DMOZ and still have yet to see it show up anywhere.

Comment: DMOZ aside, there's another valid question here, namely, why isn't there a meta tag?

Comment: @Nathan: Bitdefender blocked me from reaching your site, so that's something.

Comment: @AlEverett: Really? Did it provide any information as to why it was blocked?

Comment: @Nat: No, not really. Just "this site is not safe" and "This page is blocked by Bitdefender Cloud protection." (But none of this has anything to do with the question, so...)