# Middle clicking "Tell me more" button is redirecting on the parent page in addition to opening it in new tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow

I didn't visit Stack Overflow main page without being logged in for a long while thus not sure when this section has been added:

> > [image]

Expecting this to be an ordinary link like all others, I middle clicked it but it caused redirection (to the About page) in the parent page in addition to the new tab.

Browser: Chrome 26.0.1410.43

Edit: since others can't reproduce, here is vid showing the issue:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eFpkmLLJCJ4

Comment: @bluefeet so maybe it's browser specific, added more details to my post now. What browser are you using?

Comment: @bluefeet very weird! :/

Comment: @bluefeet that's the function of the middle click, doesn't matter what is in the code. Just tried myself, no redirect on parent page, new tab opens correctly

Comment: Middle click == open in new tab

Comment: So I take it back, I can repro this.  It's been a long day.

Comment: @bluefeet added screen capture vid.

Comment: It's currently in A/B testing http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174747/do-we-really-need-the-double-step-to-get-rid-of-the-new-about-banner, that's why not everyone can see it.

Comment: Nice @Manish didn't see your post before. Anyway that bug is likely in the JS code, unless a dev notice and fix it, it's going to stick.

Comment: It's verified on my machine.

Comment: @Sklivvz verified meaning reproduced, I hope?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yes, repro'ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hands up, I screwed this one up.

Fix in place, to be with you in the next build.

Comment: Hmm.. did you just remove the whole panel?? I can't see it anymore.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - It is in A/B testing at the moment. And it should have been off on SO (which it is now). Not trying to mess with you - promise.

Comment: OK, found it on programmers and it's indeed fixed. Cheers! :-)